# Autofill leaves blank blank cells

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

I've browsed the site looking for an answer to the following question (to no avail):

I'd like to autofill down using only the format.

In cell `T3` I have the following formula
`=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(K3:S3;"<>0");" ")`

I'd like to flashfill down from T3 to `Dim LastRow`(working variable).
I've tried copying the formula, then I get `error 1004`, for too many characters;

I tried

`Range("T3").Select
 Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("T3:T" & LastRow)`

It leaves unfilled (empty) cells

And Lastly

```
Dim dest As Range, source As Range

Set dest = WsStam.Range("T4:T" & LastRow)
Set source = WsStam.Range("T3")

source.AutoFill Destination:=dest, Type:=xlFlashFill
```

This leaves empty cells as well. (**edit** when I try the above I get "Autofill method of range class failed"

Any solutions? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the cells are actually empty and not just returning a space?

Comment: Does `Range("T3:T" & LastRow).FillDown` do it properly? You have neglected to show how LastRow is determined.

Comment: Yes, they're empty. Just clicked the cell and checked the formula bar.
And the LastRow `LastRow = WsStam.Range("S2").End(xlDown).row`

Comment: use `LastRow = WsStam.Range("S" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row` instead.

Comment: Done, doesn't help the issue though. Worked fine as it was. Did the S2 beacause I didn't count column headers. Is it much more efficient?

Comment: `Range("T3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("T3:T" & LastRow)` should work assuming `LastRow` is correctly filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Had to do with both the code and the IfError and where this was related to (these fields were empty so it didn't show a value.

The code for the filldown is:

```
WsIjk.Range("J3").AutoFill Destination:=WsIjk.Range("J3:J" & LastRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula in the question

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(K3:S3;"<>0");" ")
```

appears to have semicolon (;) which could be a reason for the issue. You would need to replace it by comma.

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(K3:S3,"<>0")," ")
```

If you have already done that, it may be possible that the `IFERROR` is returning the blank as per the condition.

Comment: some regional settings require semicolons to be used as separators, rather than commas

Comment: I was going to say that. I get an error in the worksheet when I change it to a comma.